# Is it possible to have a 'mDataProp' inside a 'fnRender' or'mRender' function using datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'm trying to do something like this in order to display values in my table: Is it possible?
Sorry If i may have completely messed up. Im trying to understand datatables.

```
aoColumns: [
     {"mRender": function(obj, val, data){

        propertySize =  data.qaccess.length;
               for(i=0; i<propertySize; i=i+1){
                col= {
                    "mDataProp": "qaccess." + i + ".product",
                    sTitle: "Account Name", sClass: "_accountName", sWidth: "25%"
                }
            }       
    }}]
The `data` above returns: out of which im trying to get the value of 'qaccess[0].product' and 'qaccess[1].product' in my table.



.   qaccess: Array[2]
.    0: Object
.       permissionIdentifiers: Array[0]
.       product: "wm.od.prod.nsr"
.       roleIdentifiers: Array[0]
.       status: "enabled"
.   1: Object
⁃       permissionIdentifiers: Array[0]
⁃       product: "gp.od.dev.nsr"
⁃       roleIdentifiers: Array[0]
⁃       status: "Active"
```

how can i achieve the values of the `qaccess` array values.
 here is the Json.

```
"updatedDate": 1408136083695,
"qaccess": [
    {
        "product": "wm.od.prod.nsr",
        "status": "enabled",
        "roleIdentifiers": [],
        "permissionIdentifiers": []
    },
    {
        "product": "gp.od.dev.nsr",
        "status": "Active",
        "roleIdentifiers": [],
        "permissionIdentifiers": []
    }
```

Please let know if you still need more details. Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you looking for sorting ? more calrity is appreciated .

Comment: no im trying to achieve the 'qaccess[0].product' and 'qaccess[1].product' values in my table.im using the 'for-loop' to loop in the value of '0,1 etc', something like this: 'qaccess[i].product' or 'qaccess. + i+ .product'. (not sure either one).